# can not install ROS in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I've been trying to install ROS in Ubuntu 13.04 for the past two weeks.  But I get an error message everytime I type in
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full

the error is "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
I've tried everything on the internet, but nothing seems to be working.  Please help me out.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-desktop : Depends: ros-hydro-common-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-geometry-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-robot but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-ros-full but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-ros-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-hydro-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187197/can-not-install-ros-in-ubuntu-13.04/) by [sis007](https://answers.ros.org/users/19796/sis007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-20**:
Please edit your question to include the full output of the error message.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-20**:
Have you enabled the universe and multiverse repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without more information, my first guess is that this is related to the fact that Ubuntu recently stopped supporting Ubuntu 13.04 and move the repository elsewhere.

See this question for more background: http://answers.ros.org/question/187016/raring-repositories-for-odroid-u3-ros-build/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2014-08-25**:
Hi ahendrix,

I have met similar problem. Have you got it fixed?

Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-25**:
I don't have this problem, so I can't confirm if the fix I suggested worked or not. Have you tried switching your sources.list to the old-releases repository, as my other answer suggests?

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Thanks for your response. I did not know how to switch my sources.list and tried several time but failed. I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 and successful installed ROS Indigo. So it must be some problems in ubuntu 13.04.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-26**:
In the future, rather than asking "did you fix this", ask a more specific question, and make it obvious that you've done some research. Maybe something like "I tried to switch my sources.list to the old-release repository, but it doesn't seem to be working"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may not be able to answer your problem, but I had this problem before. What I did is to change to ubuntu 12.04, and everything is working fine. I feel a little bit older version of ubuntu is more supported, the same way with gazebo, gazebo-3.0 is not supported with ROS while gazebo-1.9 is supported.

---

Originally posted by [KennyHimawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/18963/kennyhimawan/) with karma: 15 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1